# How to generate class from CCD schema

Tags: c#, xsd

I have tried to generate CCD.xsd to C# class file using these steps:

1. Copied the entire schema from [this example](http://developer.healthvault.com/pages/types/type.aspx?id=9c48a2b8-952c-4f5a-935d-f3292326bf54), pasted it in a notepad and saved it as an xsd file.
2. Executed the xsd command `xsd D:\ccd.xsd /c /n:CCD` from the Command Prompt (run as Administrator).
3. The ccd.cs class file was successfully created without any errors or warnings.

But I am getting this error.

```
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:hl7-org:sdtc:patient' element is not declare
d. Line 5902, position 8.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:hl7-org:sdtc:patient' element is not declare
d. Line 4868, position 8.
Schema validation warning: The 'urn:hl7-org:sdtc:patient' element is not declare
d. Line 4852, position 8.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce
 incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'ccd'.
  - The element 'urn:hl7-org:sdtc:patient' is missing.
```

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".

Comment: The `this example` link is dead or session specific. Always validate the XSD before sending it xsd.exe. Try to post the XSD or a working link for further assistance.

Comment: I updated link now you can download xsd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the warnings, you have to find the SDTC XSD (targetNamespace='urn:hl7-org:sdtc') which defines the `patient` element. Add the new file(s) to the xsd.exe command line, in addition to **ccd.xsd** (make sure that whatever files SDTC XSD needs, are also listed).

The reason why you need to add the SDTC file to the command line has to do with the fact that the ccd.xsd doesn't explicitly import the SDTC namespace.